# Magmi Magento Value Replacer issue with multiple columns

Tags: magento, magmi

I have a lot of spreadsheets which have the columns `image2` `image3` `image4` `image5` on them and I'm trying to use Magmi's Value Replacer in order to merge these to populate the `media_gallery` column. However, I've not had much luck with this and I've tried lots of different combinations. I've also looked at the Wiki and came across the following code:

```
implode(';',array_filter(array({item.Product_X}=='Y'?'Product X':'',{item.Product_Y}=='Y'?'Product Y':'',{item.Product_Z}=='Y'?'Product Z':'')))
```

Which I've then adapted for my purpose, but again, no luck here:

```
{{ implode(';',array_filter(array({item.image2}==''?'':'{item.image2}',{item.image3}==''?'':'{item.image3}',{item.image4}==''?'':'{item.image4}',{item.image5}==''?'':'{item.image5}'))) }}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Does Magmi give you any errors? (Beware you need UTF-8 format files, proper csv files, something excel doesn't give.)

Comment: No, there are no errors. Not even any warnings. But after Magento is reindexed, etc, there are no additional images.

Comment: Can you test adding a media_gallery field with static values and see if it correctly populates without a replacement?

Comment: Works perfectly fine if it's just `{{ {item.image2} }}` image2 is added, but not when I try and add more, or using the method above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to get this to work I ended up doing the following:

```
{{ implode(';',array_filter(array({item.image2},{item.image3},{item.image4},{item.image5}))) }}
```

Removing the unnecessary checks to see if item.image2 is empty or not, since array filter removes any empty values from the array anyway.

After this it worked perfectly and I now have multiple images. Hope this helps someone.